# Join more tables in one result

Tags: php, sql, join

I need help with sql select from multiply tables.

Tables:

```
s_products
- id
- name
- url
- brand_id

s_products_categories
- product_id
- category_id

s_brands
- id
- name
- url

s_categories
- id
- name
- url
```

Compare:

```
s_products.id =  s_products_categories.product_id
s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id
s_products.brand_id = s_brands.id
```

And result needed:

1) `$products['s_categories.url']['s_brands.url']['s_products.url'] = 's_products.name';`

2) `$brands['s_categories.url']['s_brands.url'] = 's_brands.name';`

Can you help me to do it in one select (or more)?

Comment: Missing column `url` in `s_products_categories`?

Comment: No, `s_products_categories` have `category_id` of `s_categories.id` where we can take a `url`

Comment: then `s_products_categories.url`, then why this in your php code?

Comment: Sorry, `s_categories.url` correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select c.url  category_url,
       c.name category_name,
       b.url  brand_url,
       b.name brand_name,
       p.url  product_url,
       p.name product_name
from s_products p
join s_brands b on p.brand_id = b.id
join s_products_categories pc on p.id = pc.product_id
join s_categories c on pc.category_id = c.id
```

To see combinations of specific fields (eg. category_url with brand_url), add `distinct` immediately after `select` and remove the fields that aren't required.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *yourcolumnsname*
from s_products INNER JOIN  s_products_categories
on s_products.id =  s_products_categories.product_id
INNER JOIN s_categories.id 
on s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id;
```

Comment: Thank's but not join `s_brands.url` =(

Comment: And my select result NULL `SELECT s_categories.url as url1, s_products.url as url2, s_products.name as name FROM s_products INNER JOIN  s_products_categories on s_products.id =  s_products_categories.product_id INNER JOIN s_categories.id on s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s_categories.url as url1, s_products.url as url2, s_products.name as name 
FROM s_products 
INNER JOIN s_products_categories on s_products.id   = s_products_categories.product_id 
INNER JOIN s_categories          on s_categories.id = s_products_categories.category_id
```